dataset map() hang and TypeError: IterableDataset.map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_proc'
I encountered a "hang" issue when using hg dataset's map(). I saw that using it while num_proc=os.cpu_count() should help, however when trying this I experienced the following error with the signature: TypeError: IterableDataset.map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_proc'
Copying here the code and error.
The relevant code sinppet:
parser = transformers.HfArgumentParser((ModelArguments, DataArguments, TrainingArguments))
model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses()

print(model_args)
print(data_args)

training_args.gradient_checkpointing_kwargs = {"use_reentrant": False}  # manually add this argument in the code
training_args.max_steps = 3

lora_config = LoraConfig(
    r=model_args.lora_r,
    lora_alpha=32,
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)

# check model_args.mem_size and min_tokens_for_lm
assert (training_args.fixed_mem_size & (training_args.fixed_mem_size - 1)) == 0, "training_args.fixed_mem_size must be a power of 2"    
assert training_args.leave_tokens_for_lm <= training_args.min_tokens_for_lm, "leave_tokens_for_lm should be fewer than min_tokens_for_lm"


memory_size = training_args.fixed_mem_size

train_file = "/storage/kohav/models/icae_new/icae/PwC_train.jsonl"
eval_file = "/storage/kohav/models/icae_new/icae/PwC_test.jsonl"

urls = [
train_file,
eval_file

]
print("Loading dataset...")

dataset = load_dataset("json", data_files={"train": train_file, "eval": eval_file}, streaming=True) # streaming can be removed if the dataset is not very large.
train_dataset = dataset["train"]
eval_dataset = dataset["eval"]

model = ICAE(model_args, training_args, lora_config)
MEM_TOKENS = list(range(model.vocab_size, model.vocab_size + memory_size))

print('dbg: os.cpu_count()=', os.cpu_count())
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(pretrain_tokenize_function, batched=True, batch_size=64, fn_kwargs={"model": model, "mem": MEM_TOKENS, "lm_ratio": training_args.lm_ratio}, num_proc=os.cpu_count())
print('dbg: finished train_dataset.map')

The error:
parser = transformers.HfArgumentParser((ModelArguments, DataArguments, TrainingArguments))
model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses()
print(model_args)
print(data_args)

training_args.gradient_checkpointing_kwargs = {"use_reentrant": False}  # manually add this argument in the code
training_args.max_steps = 3

lora_config = LoraConfig(
    r=model_args.lora_r,
    lora_alpha=32,
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)

# check model_args.mem_size and min_tokens_for_lm
assert (training_args.fixed_mem_size & (training_args.fixed_mem_size - 1)) == 0, "training_args.fixed_mem_size must be a power of 2"    
assert training_args.leave_tokens_for_lm <= training_args.min_tokens_for_lm, "leave_tokens_for_lm should be fewer than min_tokens_for_lm"


memory_size = training_args.fixed_mem_size

train_file = "/storage/kohav/models/icae_new/icae/PwC_train.jsonl"
eval_file = "/storage/kohav/models/icae_new/icae/PwC_test.jsonl"

urls = [
train_file,
eval_file

]
print("Loading dataset...")

dataset = load_dataset("json", data_files={"train": train_file, "eval": eval_file}, streaming=True) # streaming can be removed if the dataset is not very large.
train_dataset = dataset["train"]
eval_dataset = dataset["eval"]

model = ICAE(model_args, training_args, lora_config)
MEM_TOKENS = list(range(model.vocab_size, model.vocab_size + memory_size))

print('dbg: os.cpu_count()=', os.cpu_count())
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(pretrain_tokenize_function, batched=True, batch_size=64, fn_kwargs={"model": model, "mem": MEM_TOKENS, "lm_ratio": training_args.lm_ratio}, num_proc=os.cpu_count())
print('dbg: finished train_dataset.map')

Will be glad for help 
I encounter a "hang" issue when using hg dataset's map(). I saw that using it while num_proc=os.cpu_count() should help, however I experience this error with the signature: TypeError: IterableDataset.map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_proc'

IterableDatasets do not support num_proc because the dataset is (unsurprisingly) Iterable format and 1 process will do it.
I had same issue as well.... look for making multiple worker DataLoader instead... will help (https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/en/use_with_pytorch)
